# Nginx 502 Bad Gateway after Django 1.8 upgrade

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, gunicorn

I'm trying to complete the upgrade of my Django project from 1.4 to 1.8. I've got my site running locally without any issues. However when I deploy the upgraded code I get a 502 bad gateway. The site was running on the server using Django 1.4 without any issues.

The 1.4 version of the code was using Gunicorn with Supervisor. I couldn't get the upgraded code to run with Gunicorn so I tried using uWsgi, which resulted in me having the same issue.

I have other sites using Django 1.4 on this same server with are working fine.

I cant really see any useful errors in any logs, the only error I see is in the Nginx log:

`2016/02/24 10:32:16 [error] 15475#0: *52 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: [IP address], server: myapp.*, request: "GET /api/get_campaign/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/supervised-sockets/myapp-uwsgi.sock:/api/get_campaign/", host: "[site-name]"`

Nginx config:

```
upstream django {
        server unix:///var/run/supervised-sockets/myapp-uwsgi.sock;
    }

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name myapp.*;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp_error.log notice;

   # rewrite URLs of the form  static/.*/*.gz to non .gz then gzip_static module will check
    # for the compressed version on disk. Round about method to get around django-compressor
    # adding the .gz extension
    rewrite /static/(.*)\.(css|js)\.gz$ /static/$1.$2 last;
    rewrite /media/(.*)\.(css|js)\.gz$ /media/$1.$2 last;

    location /static/CACHE/ {

        root /srv/myapp/releases/current/myapp/myapp/assets/;

        expires max;
        break;
    }



    location /favicon.ico {
        root /srv/myapp/releases/current/myapp/myapp/assets/static/img/;
    }

    location /static/ {

        root /srv/myapp/releases/current/myapp/myapp/assets/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /srv/myapp/shared/;
    }

    location / {
       uwsgi_pass django;
       include /srv/myapp/releases/current/myapp/uwsgi_params;
       proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
       #proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/supervised-sockets/myapp-uwsgi.sock;
       proxy_pass http://myapp;
       proxy_buffering off;  # no need as services are local
       proxy_connect_timeout 3000s;
       proxy_read_timeout 3000s;
    }
```

This is my uWsgi ini file:

```
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /srv/myapp/releases/current/myapp
# Django's wsgi file
module          = myapp_wsgi:application
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /srv/myapp/
#virtualenv = myapp
# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 2
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /var/run/supervised-sockets/myapp-uwsgi.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket = 666
chown-socket = myapp
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
buffer-size=32768
#die-on-term = true
#wsgi-file = myapp/myapp_wsgi.py
```

When I run uWsgi this is the output:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from myapp_uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit) on [Wed Feb 24 10:45:16 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 22 February 2016 17:10:22
os: Linux-3.2.0-77-virtual #114-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 17:38:02 UTC 2015
nodename: ip-10-0-9-42
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /srv/myapp/releases/1d4cad9dae00479763636fab34ab2224a59449c4/myapp
detected binary path: /srv/myapp/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /srv/myapp/releases/current/myapp
your processes number limit is 59476
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/run/supervised-sockets/myapp-uwsgi.sock fd 3
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:25:50)  [GCC 4.6.3]
Set PythonHome to /srv/myapp/
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0xf5b420
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 304320 bytes (297 KB) for 2 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0xf5b420 pid: 30534 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 30534)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 30541, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 30542, cores: 1)
```

This is the Gunicorn config that Supervisor uses:

```
[program:myapp-gunicorn]
command=/srv/myapp/bin/gunicorn -b unix:/var/run/supervised-sockets/myapp-gunicorn.sock -w 2 myapp_wsgi:application -t 30 --max-requests 600 --timeout 300
numprocs=1
numprocs_start=0
priority=896
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=3
exitcodes=0,2
stopsignal=TERM
stopwaitsecs=60
directory=/srv/myapp/releases/current/myapp
user=myapp
redirect_stderr=false
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/myapp/myapp-gunicorn.out
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stdout_logfile_backups=5
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/myapp/myapp-gunicorn.err
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stderr_logfile_backups=5
```

This is my Django wsgi file:

```
import os
import sys

THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(THIS_DIR, "/"))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(THIS_DIR, "myapp/apps"))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(THIS_DIR, "myapp/lib"))

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myapp.settings"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any help is really appreciated as I've been looking into this for a while.

Thanks

Comment: Does it serve correctly using development server?

Comment: the only way I can get it to run is on my laptop using - python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8003

Comment: What happens on the production server?

Comment: Is there nothing at all in the gunicorn logs (myapp-gunicorn.out and myapp-gunicorn.err)?

Comment: nothing in the gunicorn logs

Comment: We need to take the extraneous things out of the equation. What happens if you start gunicorn on its own, outside of supervisor, but using the command from the supervisor config?

Comment: It runs and outputs the following: 

`[2016-02-24 11:34:41 +0000] [31470] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2016-02-24 11:34:41 +0000] [31470] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/var/run/supervised-sockets/myapp-gunicorn.sock (31470)
[2016-02-24 11:34:41 +0000] [31470] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-02-24 11:34:41 +0000] [31475] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31475
[2016-02-24 11:34:41 +0000] [31476] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31476`

Still get a 502 bad gateway

Comment: `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(THIS_DIR, "/"))` that line will add root directory of filesystem (`/`) into path, not your project dir. Be aware! Also, check if permissions to your socket file are correct (and for all parent directories), so nginx can access it.

Comment: thanks for that, will remove that line. The user in the Gunicorn config and the user permission on the sock file match.

Comment: But will it match with nginx user? chown group of socket to group that nginx runs on and try then.

Comment: which nginx file do i need to look at? the config file in sites-available?